# Homestead installation

Tags: laravel, homestead

I could not figure out where I made a mistake here. My command `vagrant up` replies with the following lines

```
$ vagrant up
Check your Homestead.yaml file, the path to your private key does not exist.
Check your Homestead.yaml file, the path to your private key does not exist.
```

[image]

Comment: **the path to your private key does not exist** do you have a private key at `~/.ssh/id_rsa` like you have configured?

Comment: And more important, what does this question have to do at all with Git? o_O

Comment: found my problem

Comment: Run this `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "you@homestead"` once and press return key 2 times and your done!

Comment: I just removed those configuration options:
authorize and keys
and it booted

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You want to follow these steps from terminal

Generate a ssh key `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

Start ssh agent `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"`

Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent `ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Then run `vagrant up`

Comment: Small edit: should have been a small 'k' in ssh-add options (`ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa`)

Comment: Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/SpiderMan/.ssh/id_rsa): id_rsa and than you'll find id_rsa named file in your Home, put in to .ssh folder.

Comment: For me, running only the first command, and then doing `vagrant up` worked.

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin It depends on the environment either in Apple - Terminal or Windows - CMD

Comment: Worx like a charm. For the record, ran this from GitBash on Windows.

Comment: I'm mac user, tried 'ss-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa' and the message was "/Users/gustavosevero/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory"

Comment: You mister is a life savior

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 were unnecessary for me. Step 1 prompts for a file name and a passphrase. It saves two files named `your-file-name` which I accidentally saved in Homestead folder. Just move those files to `~/.ssh` if they're not already there and then go to Homestead.yaml and change `authorize:` to `~/.ssh/your-file-name.pub` and `keys:` to `- ~.ssh/your-file-name`. After that ´vagrant up` works as intended.

Answer (score 56):

You don't need to generate a key. Simply run this:

`# touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Then

`# vagrant up`

Comment: Wouldn't it be better off just generating the key for future use?

Comment: It certainly would be good to do, but it's not a hard requirement of getting vagrant running. The file simply needs to exist.

Comment: or (windows) just create an empty file at c:/users/<you>/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: @Ken that is exactly what `touch` does.

Comment: @JakeWilson I know, but touch does not work on windows. At least not on my machine.

Comment: This is the best solution as it's so simple. For those on Windows, touch just creates the file so you could just create a blank file.

Comment: Not that I use Winblows anymore , but the comment for Windows could/should have been "Start - Run - type cmd , paste this command into the prompt `mkdir %userprofile/.ssh/ &&
type nul > %userprofile%/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: On macOS Monterey, in case of getting the following error:

`/Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`

do it in the following two commands:

`# mkdir ~/.ssh`
`# touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 32):

For Windows users, you can use PuTTYgen to generate public/private key pair. Then save the public key as `mypublickey.pub`. and private key as `myprivatekey.ppk`.

In `homestead.yaml` change to the following:

```
authorize: C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.ssh\mykey.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.ssh\myprivatekey.ppk
```

Comment: I think your better of when you put the file in your project directory. That way, you can pass your project to some other user, without having to regenerate the key-files, or editing the file location in the config. Of coure you delete the file when you are switching to production.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use git bash to [generate SSH keys automatically for windows](http://backendtime.com/setup-laravel-homestead-windows/)

Comment: The website no longer exists