# How to start Laravel app on Homestead / Vagrant on windows 11

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

Can't start Homestead / Vagrant on windows 11.

I tried to:

1. generate new ssh key
2. follow the steps from this post: [Homestead installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44463987/homestead-installation)
3. reinstall

When i `ssh --debug`, those are the last lines i see:

```
DEBUG virtualbox_6_1:   - [1, "ssh", 2222, 22, "127.0.0.1"]
DEBUG virtualbox_6_1:   - [1, "tcp44300", 44300, 443, ""]
DEBUG virtualbox_6_1:   - [1, "tcp8000", 8000, 80, ""]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\/ssh.EXE"]
 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...
DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO
DEBUG subprocess: stderr: usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
DEBUG subprocess: Waiting for process to exit. Remaining to timeout: 32000
DEBUG subprocess: Exit status: 255
 INFO ssh: Invoking SSH: C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\/ssh.EXE ["vagrant@127.0.0.1", "-p", "2222", "-o", "LogLevel=FATAL", "-o", "Compression=yes", "-o", "DSAAuthentication=yes", "-o", "IdentitiesOnly=yes", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-o", "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null", "-i", "C:/Users/catal/projects/my-laravel-project/.vagrant/machines/my-laravel-project/virtualbox/private_key", "-o", "ForwardAgent=yes"]
DEBUG safe_exec: Converting command and arguments to common UTF-8 encoding for exec.
DEBUG safe_exec: Command: `"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\/ssh.EXE"` Args: `["vagrant@127.0.0.1", "-p", "2222", "-o", "LogLevel=FATAL", "-o", "Compression=yes", "-o", "DSAAuthentication=yes", "-o", "IdentitiesOnly=yes", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-o", "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null", "-i", "C:/Users/catal/projects/my-laravel-project/.vagrant/machines/my-laravel-project/virtualbox/private_key", "-o", "ForwardAgent=yes"]`
DEBUG safe_exec: Converted - Command: `"C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\/ssh.EXE"` Args: `["vagrant@127.0.0.1", "-p", "2222", "-o", "LogLevel=FATAL", "-o", "Compression=yes", "-o", "DSAAuthentication=yes", "-o", "IdentitiesOnly=yes", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-o", "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null", "-i", "C:/Users/catal/projects/my-laravel-project/.vagrant/machines/my-laravel-project/virtualbox/private_key", "-o", "ForwardAgent=yes"]`
```